# Draw a vertical line upward with CSS3 SVG animation

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I am very new in SVG animation. How can I grow a vertical line with CSS3 SVG animation? The line should start from the bottom and grow upward to custom height (Ex. 0 to 100). I have the code below:

```
<svg height="210" width="10">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:3" />
</svg>
```

This is the initial position. I have tried increasing the `y2` value, but then it grows downward, which I do not want. Please show me an example with CSS3 keyframe animation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Decrease either y1 or y2.

Answer (score 0):

Usually to animate the process of drawing a curve one, one animates the stroke-dashoffset. Here's a fairly simple example:

```
<path fill="url(#rg)" transform="translate(7,5) scale(.62)" stroke="url(#rg)" stroke-opacity=".6" stroke-width="15" stroke-dasharray="45 45" fill-rule="evenodd" 
      d="M64,33 c27 -16,89,0,68,22 C103,84,41,39,13,67 c-24,24,20,49,42,43 C103,97,78,0,36,1 C10,1.5 -3,28,2,52 c3,12,10,22,21,27 c8,3,21,5,29,2 c16-4,8-26,16 -36 c7-10,26-7,34.73 0 c21,16,11,64-1,83 c-6,9-20,17-31,13 c-14 -5-12-24-14-36 C52,82,39,47,64,33z">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;900;1800" dur="45s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</path>
```

(same thing for a line -- just a simple case of a path -- just make sure the values are large enough to cover the whole line.
Working example: http://cs.sru.edu/%7Eddailey/tangles/drawingcurve.svg
(the gradient is only there to make it pretty)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CSS animation for this because, currently, SVG geometry attributes are not modifiable with CSS.  Only styling properties are.

The origin of an SVG is at the top left, not the bottom-left as you might be expecting.  So if you want to draw a line that starts at the bottom and grows upwards you need to start with a high Y coordinate value and then reduce it.

Here's an example SVG with two lines. The green one is half the height of the other, and the both start at the same bottom coordinate.

```html
<svg height="210" width="10">
    <line x1="2" y1="0" x2="2" y2="210" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:3" />
    <line x1="8" y1="100" x2="8" y2="210" style="stroke:rgb(0,128,0);stroke-width:3" />
</svg>
```